# XQuery: Fill array the FLWOR way

Tags: xquery, basex, flwor

I have an array and I want to fill it with strings taken from specific XML nodes, like in this pseudocode example:

```
let $array := array {}

for $child in $collection
where contains(data($child), "Hey")
do $array := array:append($array, data($child))
```

How would correct code look like to perform such an operation?

So if I have this XML

```
<root>
    <child>Hey</child>
    <child>Ho</child>
    <child>Hey Ho</child>
</root>
```

I expect the array to be

```
array ["Hey", "Hey Ho"]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

XQuery is a functional language. As such, variables cannot be reassigned once they have been declared.

The following code should do the trick:

```
array {
  for $child in $collection
  where contains(data($child/node1), "Hey")
  return $child/node2
}
```

Please note that the native XQuery data type for values is a sequence. Depending on your use case, maybe you don’t need arrays at all.

Comment: Or more simply, and closer to the supplied XML, `array{ $collection[contains(.,"Hey")] }`

Comment: Right. It seems that the original question was edited after I had placed my answer.